# Show Programming Syntax Highlighting with Dynamic Blogger themes?

Tags: syntax, coding-style, themes, blogger, posts

I use blogger to create posts relating to some programming languages. With Simple Themes in blogger.com the programming syntax could be set to be seen with various styles, that sets it apart from the rest of the text.

But, with dynamic themes any of those things don't work. What to do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "syntax highlighting", and there are numerous JavaScript pacakges out there that will do it.  I suspect that you can integrate some JavaScript into your Blogger templates, no?

A zillion articles came up when I Googled on "javascript syntax highlighting blogger".  Go to it.

Comment: thanks for enlightening me.